# Facebook API Why image not upload in post?

Tags: facebook

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
            caption: 'test: '+ Link,
            description: '',
            to: *******,
            picture: 'https://SITE.com/UserGifts/ImageMail/1402530327.jpg',
            link: Link,
            redirect_uri: Link,
    }, function(response){});
```

When code is start we see [image]

Tell me please why image not upload with post?

P.S.: Image exist on server, console not have error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
https://example.com/UserGifts/ImageMail/1402530327.jpg
```

on

```
http://example.com/UserGifts/ImageMail/1402530327.jpg
```

Where `example` is name your site(`SITE`)

P.S.: not use `https` on url image, use only `http`.